# Appium - Very fragile when running tests through Android device

Tags: android, selenium, testng, appium

after much overthinking I was finally able to get a test to run through my physical device using appium! It ran so well, I had to see it do run again.. Only problem is that it didnt. I stopped the appium server, turned on the option for "Override Existing Session" and kicked it back off. Now I started to get ChromeUnreachable and Screen did not unlock errors. I restarted the device and hey, the test ran! It seemed to work as soon as I would restart the device...

Now I am starting to think that while I may be close, I may not be configuring it exactly right. If someone can take a look at my setup and let me know if something looks off, or if something worked for you I would be very thankful. I run them through a testng xml file.. I apologize for the screenshots, but I think they will be useful for anyone else with a similar issue.
[image: Android Settings in Appium]

My Server Adress configuration is : 127.0.0.1:4237 (default)

And here is my xml file with the capability paramaters..

```
<test name="MyAtc SavedListings SavedSearches">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="ZX1D3286W7"/>
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
        <parameter name="browserName" value="Chrome"/>
        <parameter name="local" value="false"/>
        <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https://magic1.web.com/"/>
        <parameter name="bsAccount" value="http://127.0.0.1:4237/wd/hub"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testsuites.regression.Regression"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

Also, yes I have updated my chrome on the device to the latest version and I use a

Comment: Appium could be a bit fussy sometimes, so you have to try to understand what are the parameters necessary to run your tests and properly run the server... Your `testng` looks fine. Did you try marking the `Use browser` checkbox in the Appium app? This gave me some trouble at first.

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately that made it even more unstable for me.. I think I may have found a solution.. Test is running smooth now but I need to run it twice to make sure.

Comment: I had the same issue with "Override Existing Session" . Skipping it in the server arguments is a better idea.

Comment: @Vvvaib, I have thought this same thing! What was your work around for that?

Comment: @Tree55Topz - I was trying to fix some runtime execution issue while running scripts on mobile browsers. I just tried this argument and landed into more trouble so reverted it. Probably this doesn't answers your question. But, what are you trying to fix by adding this argument in your server ?